# write the data to saved excel without affecting the format

Tags: php, excel, fopen, fwrite

I have saved excel sheet on my server,it has an format i trying to write data to the saved excel but when i trying write its removing the excel format (i.e it removing header color everything) it write start data in the first cell,i want to write the data to saved excel without changeling the excel format start from cell 10, below is the image how my excel looks like before performing the function.
and after how its,looks like.

before:

[image]

after

[image]

mycode

```
<?php


$File = "Book1.xls";   

 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 $Data = "Abdul Rahim\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
 $Data = "Raja\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
 print "Data Written"; 
 fclose($Handle); 

?>
```

can anyone help me how to do this .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write the data to existing excel without affecting the excel format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325813/how-to-write-the-data-to-existing-excel-without-affecting-the-excel-format)

Comment: The answer hasn't changed since you last asked this exact question.

Comment: If you're working with an actual Excel file that supports formatting, then you can't simply append data to it; you need to use one of the many libraries that supports the file format... I'd recommend my own PHPExcel

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the XLS just with `fwrite`. It has a strict format.

You could switch to CSV or use a third-party library like [PhpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).